# sympy - substitute a specific power

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equality.

```
import sympy as sp
D, L, V = sp.symbols("D, L, V", real=True, positive=True)
Veq = sp.Eq(V, sp.pi * D**3 / 4 * (sp.Rational(2, 3) + L / D))
```

I would like to solve `Veq` for `D**3`. If I try a direct approach, `sp.solve(Veq, D**3)` the computation is going to take a while eventually giving me a tremendously long result (useless to me).

My attempt: trying to substitute `D**3` with a new symbol, then solve for it. Unfortunately, the substitution is also going to replace the other `D` in the equality:

```
t = sp.symbols("t")
print(Veq.subs(D**3, t))

>>> Eq(V, pi*t*(L/t**(1/3) + 2/3)/4)
```

Note the term `L/t**(1/3)`. I would like it to be `L/D` after the substitution. So far I've managed to manipulate the expression and reaching my goal with this code:

```
res = sp.Mul(*[a.subs(D**3, sp.symbols("t")) if a.has(D**3) else a for a in asd.args[1].args])
Veq = sp.Eq(V, res)
print(Veq)

>>> Eq(V, pi*t*(2/3 + L/D)/4)
```

I'm wondering, is there some flag for `subs` that I can use to reach my goal? Or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the substitution to be exact you can use the `exact` flag:

```
>>> var('D V L')
(D, V, L)
>>> Veq = sp.Eq(V, sp.pi * D**3 / 4 * (sp.Rational(2, 3) + L / D))
>>> Veq.subs(D**3,y,exact=True)
Eq(V, pi*y*(2/3 + L/D)/4)
>>> solve(Veq.subs(D**3,y,exact=True),y)
[12*D*V/(pi*(2*D + 3*L))]
```

The `exact` flag appears to be ignore when assumptions are given:

```
>>> D, L, V = symbols("D, L, V", real=True, positive=True)
>>> (D**3+D).subs(D**3,y,exact=True)
y**(1/3) + y
>>> D, L, V = symbols("D, L, V")
>>> (D**3+D).subs(D**3,y,exact=True)
D + y
```

You can use `replace` for your situation:

```
>>> D, L, V = symbols("D, L, V", real=True, positive=True)
>>> (D**3+D).replace(D**3,y)
D + y
```

But since your expression is a Relational you have to use replace on the arguments, not the Relational (or else you will get an error):

```
>>> eq = Eq(D**3, D - 1)
>>> eq.func(*[a.replace(D**3,y) for a in eq.args])
Eq(y, D - 1)
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind to tell me which version of sympy you are using? I've tried the `exact=True` on version 1.4 and it doesn't work...

Comment: 1.5 (available online through repl.it)

Comment: I can confirm @JohanC : exact=True is accepted but it does also replace `D`. I've tried this with sympy 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.1. All of them installed with pip3.

Comment: updated -- the assumptions allow the replacement. I didn't use assumptions in the example I gave.

Comment: Thanks @smichr ! I'll accept your answer. Can you please update it to say that `replace()` only works with sympy expressions, not with Relationals? (which is different than `subs()`) So for my specific case I should use `Veq = sp.Eq(*[a.replace(D**3, y) for a in Veq.args])`. Thank you!!!